# Vue prototype in external JS files and access to the vuex $store

Tags: vue.js, module, prototype, vuex

I have setup a vue prototype

```
Vue.prototype.$preventAccess = function (role ) {

if(role === this.$store.state.role) {
// do some stuff

}

}
```

this is in my main entry point however when I try to use it in an external module (prevent.js)

```
import store from '@store/store';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default function log({ next, to }) {
  console.log(Vue.prototype.$preventAccess('Editor'));
}
```

I get the error

```
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Can I not use my prototype in an external JS file like this? How do I inject the store into the external module?

Comment: Without prototype should work : Vue.$preventAccess = function

Comment: no that just breaks it elsewhere in the app.

Comment: Maybe you have to create a plugin to do what you want : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation here :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

```
MyPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  
  // 4. add an instance method
  Vue.prototype.$preventAccess = function (role) {
    // some logic ...
  }
}

Vue.use(MyPlugin);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `prototype` you have access to a `this` when you create an object based on that `class`.

When accessing `Vue.prototype.$preventAccess` there is no `this`, because there is no instance of `Vue` so there is no `this` created.

Your call would work if you instantiate `Vue` and call `$preventAccess` on that instance.

```
var app = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
})
app.$preventAccess()
```

Now, `$preventAccess` has a `this` defined.